# Storing images in core data

Tags: ios, core-data

Should we use core data store images? Is that considered a good practise? I think it might have less memory foot prints since core data faults objects until they are actually accessed.

Comment: If you store images into core data then it will make your database heavy. I guess if you store the images with some unique name in memory and file path into the database it may be good. But I think it may be tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ideal.

People do it (including me).  I use a data converter, works nicely.

One option is to store the filename.

There will be a better option in upcoming releases of CoreData.

Answer (score 0):

Actually according apple documentation you should use core data depending on the file size: see this chapter on core data programing guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Performance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH25-SW11

> Large Data Objects (BLOBs)
>
> If your application uses large BLOBs ("Binary Large OBjects" such as image and sound data), you need to take care to minimize overheads. The exact definition of “small”, “modest”, and “large” is fluid and depends on an application’s usage. A loose rule of thumb is that objects in the order of kilobytes in size are of a “modest” sized and those in the order of megabytes in size are “large” sized. Some developers have achieved good performance with 10MB BLOBs in a database. On the other hand, if an application has millions of rows in a table, even 128 bytes might be a "modest" sized CLOB (Character Large OBject) that needs to be normalized into a separate table.
>
> In general, if you need to store BLOBs in a persistent store, **you should use an SQLite store.** The XML and binary stores require that the whole object graph reside in memory, and store writes are atomic (see “Persistent Store Features” (page 130)) which means that they do not efficiently deal with large data objects. SQLite can scale to handle extremely large databases. Properly used, SQLite provides good performance for databases up to 100GB, and a single row can hold up to 1GB (although of course reading 1GB of data into memory is an expensive operation no matter how efficient the repository).
>
> A BLOB often represents an attribute of an entity—for example, a photograph might be an attribute of an Employee entity. For small to modest sized BLOBs (and CLOBs), you should create a separate entity for the data and create a to-‐one relationship in place of the attribute. For example, you might create Employee and Photograph entities with a one-‐to-‐one relationship between them, where the relationship from Employee to Photograph replaces the Employee's photograph attribute. This pattern maximizes the benefits of object faulting (see “Faulting and Uniquing” (page 110)). Any given photograph is only retrieved if it is actually needed (if the relationship is traversed).
>
> It is better, however, if you are able to store BLOBs as resources on the filesystem, and to maintain links (such as URLs or paths) to those resources. You can then load a BLOB as and when necessary.